# Intercepting HTTP event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JQuery code working however I need to know whether how to actually get the URL executed from the tags selected.

```
$("link, script, style, a, img").each(function () {
    $(this).load(function () {
        // get the URL and log it
        console.log("Intercepted HTTP Event");
    });
});
```

First thing I need to do it to get the actual URL during the load.

Next thing I may need to do is to actually catch before the load event happens, I mean before an image or link is loaded for example. Also, I need to modify the URL of the event that will be executed, for example, `img` tag has `src="/somewhere/image.png"` I mean, this will cause a `GET /somewhere/image.png` I may need to change it to `GET/otherplace/image.png`

Any ideas how to achive any of these?

Comment: A question, why not use mod_rewrite? Host limitation?

Comment: Not really, I am not rewriting to a specific proxy. I need to check how the page works in the client before it does anything on the server side...

Comment: Then use mod_rewrite in your development machine.

Comment: Very hard to achieve first part (track all load events) and impossible to achieve second part (replace urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.attr('src')

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).load()` will fire *after* the contents of the element have been loaded. So you may be able to grab the URL by doing `$(this).attr("src")` or `$(this).attr("href")`, but it's already too late to stop the HTTP requests from going out.

AFAIK, with modern browsers, there's no way for JavaScript to prevent assets from being loaded in the first place. At best, you may be able to change images and stylesheets after the page has been loaded, by changing the `src` attributes. If you do this, make sure that `$(this).load()` doesn't go into an infinite loop. (`<a>` links are less of a problem. Nothing is loaded, so just change the `href` attribute.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the reason I need to catch events is because the HTTP event like GET /something.png is generated by another javascript on the page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem would be to have some dummy links/hidden controls with the source of your external resource and once the page loads you go through all such controls and then create the respective html elements, update the src attribute and then append it to the dom.

Dummy Controls:

```
<input type="hidden" source="/my/source/a.jpg" nodeType="img" class="specialControls"/>
<input type="hidden" source="/my/source/1.js" nodeType="script" class="specialControls" />
```

and the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $(".specialControls").each(function(){
        var elementType=$(this).attr("nodeType");
        $('<'+elementType+'/>').attr('src', $(this).attr("source"))
                           .insertAfter($(this))

    });

});
```

Hope this helps.